# $scope is not updating after async call AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that is making an API call, grabbing a path to a JSON file, and then running that through a proxy to get around CORS and then returning a value to my controller, I can get it to `console.log()`but am unable to update anything in my HTML when the function is ran, I have tried `$scope.$apply` but got a digest error. Also tried using $scope.$applyAsync()

**My Service**

```
mywow.service('auctionService', function($http) {
    this.getData = function(realmName) {
        return $http.get('https://us.api.battle.net/wow/auction/data/' + realmName + '?locale=en_US&apikey=xxxx').
        then(function(response) {
            var urlToJsonFileUncut = response.data.files[0].url;
            urlToJsonFile = urlToJsonFileUncut.slice(7);
            console.log("URL to JSON file: " + urlToJsonFile);

            return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/' + urlToJsonFile).
            then(function(response) {
                console.log("Response from Service: " + response.data.realms[0].name);
                return response.data.realms[0].name;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**My Controller**

```
   //Auction controller
mywow.controller('auctionCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray, auctionService, $timeout, $q) {
    var self = this;
    self.realms = loadAll();
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchText = null;
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    $scope.test = "waiting for you to choose!"; //here is where I assigned test
    //search
    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.realms.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.realms;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    //get all of the realms
    function loadAll() {
        var allRealms = "Wyrmrest Accord, Ysera, Ysondre, Zangarmarsh, Zul'jin, Zuluhed";
        return allRealms.split(/, +/g).map(function(realm) {
            return {
                value: realm.toLowerCase(),
                display: realm
            };
        });
    };
    //chnage realm to lowercase
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(realm) {
            return (realm.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    };

    //send realm name to auction service and run the call
    function Init(realmNameFromGo) {
        auctionService.getData(realmNameFromGo).then(function(data) {
            console.log("From controller: " + data);
            $scope.realmName = data;
        });
    };


    //Go button
    $scope.realmGo = function() {
        Init(self.selectedItem.value);
    };


});
```

**My HTML**

```
    <div ng-controller="auctionCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" name="realmNameSelection">
      <p>Please select a realm to begin API queries</p>
      <div layout-gt-sm="row">
        <md-autocomplete flex="45" required
            md-input-name="autocompleteField"
            md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
            md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display"
            md-floating-label="Realm"
            md-require-match
            >
          <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
          </md-item-template>
          <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
            <div ng-message="md-required">Please type, then select an existing realm.</div>
            <div ng-message="md-require-match">Please select an existing state.</div>
          </div>
        </md-autocomplete>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="realmNameSelection.$invalid" ng-click="realmGo()">GO!</md-button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </md-content>
</div>



<p>{{test}}</p>
  <p>Selected Realm: {{ realmName }}</p>

<div layout="row">
    <div flex="25" hide-sm hide-xs>
        <md-content flex layout-align="center center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare, cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.</p>
        </md-content>
    </div>
    <div flex="50" hide-sm hide-xs>
        <md-content flex layout-align="right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare, cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.</p>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: service looks fine, the function from the controller as well and it's all done via angular `$http` so you don't need the `$applyAsync`. Are you sure that the template is in the scope of the controller?

Comment: Yeah, in my HTML I also have a <p>{{test}}</p> and am assigning it in the same controller, and that is pulling through fine. Also no console errors or anything. Is there anything else I should try, or check?

Comment: is that `{{test}}` somewhere near the `realmName`? sometimes it might be not closed tag or some typo that will change the expected DOM structure

Comment: I added the whole HTML file, {{test}} is right above it, and all of the code above it is Angular Material's autocomplete input.

Comment: I don't know where that `{{test}}` is coming from but the realm is outside of the DIV to which `auctionCtrl as ctrl` is assigned, move it into the div and check again

Comment: Wow... That did it.. I assigned $scope.test in the beginning of my controller (not inside any function, but in the controller nevertheless) so now I am confused, I will post my whole controller and maybe you could shed some light as to why that happened?